# Will a sector colonize planets in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

If there are planets suitable for colonization in a sector, will the sector colonize them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to not be the case that a sector governor will actively colonize planets, at least in my experience since i had to build ships and send them on their way even if a sector had planets with 95% habitability.

It might be that case that they start doing that if you wait long enough (maybe the a.i. only settles on 100% habitable planets, i don't know) or chose a different focus for the sector but it certainly doesn't look like that's a likely scenario.

Also i think it's not even bad that sectors don't colonize new planets since the colony ships have rather high maintenance and if sectors would build them on their own it could ruin your economy which is something that players most certainly do not want. 
Besides, settling on planets could significantly raise your overall population count which can lead to extremely long research times for new technologies. I think both those things are the reason for sectors not colonizing, because it could really screw with your empire in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Can the empire colonize a planet in a Sector?

Comment: @ShloEmi absolutely, just send the ship there and let them colonize the planet, as soon as that's over the sector will take over management of your new planet.

Comment: "Also i think it's not even bad that sectors don't colonize new planets since the colony ships have rather high maintenance and if sectors would build them on their own it could ruin your economy" - This isn't entirely correct. Sectors have their own economy, so the effect on your empire economy is reduced (depending on how much the sector gives you). A sector running a deficit doesn't earn anything anyway, so it won't effect your economy. Additionally, if oyu want a sector to build up, you'll likely set their tribute to 0%, meaning it also doesn't have an effect on your economy.

Comment: @Dulkan good point. i was just thinking about it in terms of sectors contributing to the overall economy, since i usually have a few sectors producing money and the rest for research, in this constellation a burdened sector economy would also hurt the empire but in a different setup this might not be the case at all.

Comment: This answer might be out of date. After a recent patch, one of the settings for a sector is whether or not it is allowed to colonize. (I haven't tried whether it works)